# SUM value showing wrong in SSAS MDX query

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube

I have SSAS cube there is a column called 'waittime' which is contain 'NULL' values referring that i need to create measure total SUM.

my query be like:
sum([Measures].[WaitTime])

but result is wrong it showing - negative total because of NULL, How to exclude NULL ?

sum([Measures].[WaitTime])

Comment: use coalesce https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/mdx/coalesceempty-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: could you please explain on this in query

Answer (score 0):

`CoalesceEmpty` checks if the value is NULL or Empty and uses then the second parameter.

```
SUM(CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[WaitTime], 0))
```

more in the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/mdx/coalesceempty-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16)